# How do I split a stack of consumable items?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I've got a stack of potions. Five of them in fact. It sure would be nice if I could put one of them into each of my party members quick slots for use in this really hard boss fight I have coming up. The usual suspects for stack splitting - shift click, control click, alt click, click, then shift click to drop, don't seem to be working, so...

How in the hell do I split up my nice stack of potions before the big fight?

Comment: Did you try the old shift-click-drag?

Comment: @StrixVaria Yeah.

Answer (score 11):

Double-click the stacked items, choose how many instances of the items you want to move, and click accept.

Comment: No need for ctrl -- just double click.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried Control + drag the item in the same bag and it showed the option to split the items.